# How to pass lambda parameters in rails 4 with multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, lambda, scope, model-associations

I have been trying to implement multiple associations between 2 models for a chess game.

I created models for user and game as follows:

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games

  # scope to define games as all games played by given user
  def games
    Game.user_games(self)
  end
end


class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :white_user, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :black_user, class_name: 'User'

  # scope that returns all games where user is white or black 
  def self.user_games(user)
    where('white_user_id = ? OR black_user_id = ?', user.id, user.id)
  end
end
```

I manage to get this working, but when I tried to refactor this using scope with Lambda notation, I cannot seem to get user model to pass the user object to scope in game model that looks up the sql query.

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games, ->(user){ Game.user_games(user) }
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :white_user, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :black_user, class_name: 'User'

  scope :user_games, ->(user){ 
    where('white_user_id = ? OR black_user_id = ?', user.id, user.id)
  }
end
```

What is the correct syntax to get this to work? Thanks!